# JHTML generic list add data attributes to options Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I need to add data attributes to individual options in a JHtml generic list in Joomla 2.5.

In standard html, the select list looks like:

```
<select class="field" placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('COUNTRY')?>" name="country" id="country" autofocus="autofocus" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Country</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan" data-alternative-spellings="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Åland Islands" data-alternative-spellings="AX Aaland Aland" data-relevancy-booster="0.5">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="Albania" data-alternative-spellings="AL">Albania</option>
...
</select>
```

Normally when creating an option I would do:

```
$options=array();
$options[]=JHTML::_( 'select.option', "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan" );
$options[]=JHTML::_( 'select.option', "Albania", "Albania" );
...

 $dropdown = JHTML::_('select.genericlist',$options,'country','id="country" autofocus="autofocus" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off"','value','text',$default);
```

How would I add the   data-alternative-spellings="AF"     to each option?

Thanks

Comment: Hate to say it, but JHtmlSelect::option() doesn't have any provision to add this.

Comment: Cool feature idea, but I think as of now you'd need to extend it.

Comment: Agree with the above, you would likely have to roll your own. JHTML's register function allows you to add your own options.

Comment: Ok, looks like I will have to extend it.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is in fact possible:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'value' => 'redapple',
        'text' => 'Red apple',
        'attr' => array('data-price'=>'5'),
    ),
    array(
        'value' => 'greenapple',
        'text' => 'Green apple',
        'attr' => array('data-price'=>'3'),
    ),
);

$options = array(
    'id' => 'applesfield', // HTML id for select field
    'list.attr' => array( // additional HTML attributes for select field
        'class'=>'field-apples',
    ),
    'list.translate'=>false, // true to translate
    'option.key'=>'value', // key name for value in data array
    'option.text'=>'text', // key name for text in data array
    'option.attr'=>'attr', // key name for attr in data array
    'list.select'=>'greenapple', // value of the SELECTED field
);

$result = JHtmlSelect::genericlist($data,'apples',$options);
```

This will result in:

```
<select id="applesfield" name="apples" class="field-apples">
    <option value="redapple" data-price="5">Red apple</option>
    <option value="greenapple" data-price="3" selected="selected">Green apple</option>
</select>
```

Explanation:
I had already extended **JHtmlSelect** and overridden **genericlist()** when I found out I really on needed to set an option for genericlist(): **'option.attr'**.

The parameters of JHtmlSelect::genericlist() are rather complicated, but simply: if the third parameter is *array* and it's the last parameter you pass, it will be used to populate genericlist's options.

**'option.attr'** will set the **key** for your *option's extra attributes*. If this is set, you can add as many attributes to your options as you like, as shown in the **$data** array above.